# Predicting probability of patterns from a dynamic unordered set

Tags: algorithm, probability, pattern-recognition

Let's say a user can input one of three distinct elements: `{A, B, C}`

As the user continues to put in these values, is there a way to predict probabilities of which value would be next, which next two values, and which next three?

If so, can you please reference me to an algorithm that I can read up on? Or some code samples?

Comment: n-grams work well if the data has some language-like structure. In cases like Random or Algorithmic data (such as A,B,C,AA,BB,CC,AAA,BBB,CCC) you'll need a customized approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). You can use them to determine the probability of the next character(s) given the recent characters entered.